# Sorting issue with 2D array in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, sorting, comparator

With my following code I try to sort a two dimensional array

```
 int[][] d2 = {
           {4,5,1},
           {4,1,1},
           {1,7,1},
           {3,3,2},
           {1}
          };

        java.util.Arrays.sort(d2, new java.util.Comparator<int[]>() {
            public int compare(int[] a, int[] b) {
                return a[0] - b[0];
            }
        });
```

I display the array after sorting

```
for (int r=0; r<d2.length; r++) {
            for (int c=0; c<d2[r].length; c++) {
                System.out.print(" " + d2[r][c]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
}
```

The Result I get is like this

```
 1 7 1
 1
 3 3 2
 4 5 1
 4 1 1
```

I want the result two come  like this

```
 1
 1 7 1
 3 3 2
 4 5 1
 4 1 1
```

What is required to be done to get the array sorted like the above?

I tried replacing the `{1}` with `{1,0,0}` but it still gives the same result even for `{1,0,1}`.

Comment: You need to add more condition in the comparator (return the difference in array length if first element is equal).

Comment: do you want the comparison only on 1st elements?

Comment: I agree with @nhahtdh, you need to modify your compare method to handle the length of the arrays too.

Comment: @Sangeet Menon: Could you please state how you wan't arrays with the same first element should be sorted?   Also it would be helpful to know how you would like to treat arrays of different lengths: By length only or by their elements also?

Comment: @SangeetMenon.. Do remember to accept one of the answers, that satisfies your need..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compare the length of passed array in the `compare` method.. If length of `a[]` is less than `b[]`, return -1: -

```
    java.util.Arrays.sort(d2, new java.util.Comparator<int[]>() {
                public int compare(int[] a, int[] b) {
                    if (a.length != b.length) {
                        return a.length < b.length ? -1 : 1;
                    }
                    return a[0] - b[0];
                }
            });
```

If you want to sort, by checking each element, which I think you should do this way.. Change your `compare` method to: -

```
public int compare(int[] a, int[] b) {

    if (a.length == b.length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] == b[i]) {

            } else {
                return a[i] - b[i];
            }
        }
        return 0;

    } else {
        return a.length < b.length ? -1 : 1;
    }                       
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP wants - you need to compare `a[i]-b[i]` until one of the array's length is reached and compare the other items with 0 (I suppose).

Comment: @assylias.. May be, but when I saw the expected output of OP, I though he wants this only.. You can see there.. He is not comparing all the elements..

Comment: @assylias How do I compare all the elements?

Comment: @assylias.. Edited the code to consider both the cases.. OP can choose whatever he wants now.. :)

Comment: @RohitJain OP is just trying to sort on first elements, i guess. my answer explains the reasons of results that OP gets.

Comment: @VincenzoSanchez.. I know he was sorting based on the first element only.. I have added the code for that, and also for sorting based on all the elements..

Answer (score 0):

In your `Comperator` you only use the first field to compare 2 arrays. You have to include all the fields to compare them or at least you have to check the length of the arrays to get your desired result.